# Swift function to interpret Roman numerals (ported from JavaScript)

Tags: error-handling, swift, number-systems

I have written some Swift for the first time, being competent enough in Javascript and having some experience in Ruby and Python.  For my education, I've written a function that parses a roman numeral string and returns its integer representation, first in Javascript (ES2015+):

> ```
> const dict = [
>   ['CM', 900], ['M', 1000], ['CD', 400], ['D', 500],
>   ['XC', 90], ['C', 100], ['XL', 40], ['L', 50],
>   ['IX', 9], ['X', 10], ['IV', 4], ['V', 5],
>   ['I', 1],
> ]
>
> function romanToInt (original) {
>   let temp = original
>   let int = 0
>
>   while (temp.length > 0) {
>     let found = false
>
>     for (const [glyph, quantity] of dict) {
>       if (temp.startsWith(glyph)) {
>         int += quantity
>         temp = temp.slice(glyph.length)
>         found = true
>         break
>       }
>     }
>
>     if (!found) {
>       // e.g. Error parsing roman numeral "MDCCLXXVI," at ","
>       throw new Error(`Error parsing roman numeral "${original}" at "${temp}"`)
>     }
>   }
>
>   return int
> }
>
> try {
>   romanToInt('MMXIV') // => 2014
> } catch (err) {
>   console.error(err)
> }
> ```

and then ported it to Swift 4:

```
let dict: [( glyph: String, quantity: Int )] = [
    ("CM", 900), ("M", 1000), ("CD", 400), ("D", 500),
    ("XC", 90), ("C", 100), ("XL", 40), ("L", 50),
    ("IX", 9), ("X", 10), ("IV", 4), ("V", 5),
    ("I", 1)
]

enum RomanNumericError: Error {
    case badInput(original: String, temp: String)
}

func romanToInt(original: String) throws -> Int {
    var temp = original
    var int = 0

    while temp.count > 0 {
        var found = false

        for (glyph, quantity) in dict {
            if temp.starts(with: glyph) {
                int += quantity
                temp.removeFirst(glyph.count)
                found = true
                break
            }
        }

        guard found == true else {
            throw RomanNumericError.badInput(original: original, temp: temp)
        }
    }

    return int
}

do {
    try romanToInt(original: "MMXIV") // => 2014
} catch RomanNumericError.badInput(let original, let temp) {
    print("Error parsing roman numeral '\(original)' at '\(temp)'")
}
```

I'm wondering about how swift-y my code is in terms of design patterns, especially in terms of error handling. In Javascript, throwing and catching errors is a very common control flow design, and I'm wondering if I'm approaching it from the right angle in Swift.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's do this from inside out. `temp.starts(with: glyph)` is correct, but
there is also a dedicated method `temp.hasPrefix(glyph)` for strings.

The loop to find the first dictionary entry with a matching prefix
can be shortened to

```
guard let (glyph, quantity) = dict.first(where: { temp.hasPrefix($0.glyph) }) else {
    throw RomanNumericError.badInput(original: original, temp: temp)
}
```

(also making the `var found` obsolete.)

Mutating the temporary string can be avoided by working with a `SubString` (which is a kind of view into the original string) and
only updating the current search position:

```
var pos = original.startIndex
while pos != original.endIndex {
    let subString = original[pos...]
    // ...
    pos = original.index(pos, offsetBy: glyph.count)
}
```

*Naming:* This is very opinion-based, here are my opinions:

- Declare the function as `func romanToInt(_ roman: String)`,
  so that it is called without (external) argument name:
  `romanToInt("MMXIV")`.
- Rename `var int` to `var value`.
- `dict` is also a non-descriptive name (and it is not even a dictionary), something like `glyphsAndValues` might be a better choice.

Summarizing the suggestions so far, we have

```
func romanToInt(_ roman: String) throws -> Int {
    var value = 0
    var pos = roman.startIndex
    while pos != roman.endIndex {
        let subString = roman[pos...]
        guard let (glyph, quantity) = glyphsAndValues.first(where: { subString.hasPrefix($0.glyph) }) else {
            throw RomanNumericError.badInput(roman: roman, at: subString)
        }
        value += quantity
        pos = roman.index(pos, offsetBy: glyph.count)
    }
    return value
}
```

---

Now the error handling. Yes, throwing an error is a good and Swifty
way to report a failure to the caller. (An alternative is to return an
*optional* value which is `nil` in the error case, but that does not
allow to provide additional error information.)

The creation of the error message however should be done in the
error class, by adopting the [`LocalizedError`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/localizederror) protocol:

```
enum RomanNumericError: Error {
    case badInput(roman: String, at: Substring)
}

extension RomanNumericError: LocalizedError {
    public var errorDescription: String? {
        switch self {
        case .badInput(let roman, let at):
            return "Error parsing roman numeral '\(roman)' at '\(at)'"
        }
    }
}
```

The big advantage is that the caller does not need to know *which*
error the function throws, and can catch a generic `Error`:

```
do {
    try print(romanToInt("MMXIV"))
    try print(romanToInt("MMYXIV"))
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}

// Output:
//   2014
//   Error parsing roman numeral 'MMYXIV' at 'YXIV'
```

Comment: Really helpful, thank you. I have trouble using the `LocalizedError` protocol though; it throws a `error: use of undeclared type 'LocalizedError'` (Xcode 9.2, in a playground). I'm investigating why, but if you have a clue, I'd be glad to hear it.

Comment: You may need to import Foundation.

Comment: Thanks, your comment and this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33943477/import-swift-vs-import-foundation clarified the situation.